# Adding new Service-based database to C# project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

Lately i was building C# windows forms application with service-based database.
I was forced to make few changes to make it work, but it's still not working as it should.
I'am doing this at start:

```
1. Add Service-based database to project
2. Create Tables
3. Add Entity framework 6.1.2 Model to project
```

This creates seccond database file in Project and in Data Connection. Now if i want to show any data, I must create dgv and dataSet pointing at this newly created .mdf file. Also i need to change Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer. Now I can see my data, but i only see empty table in Data Connection in Server Explorer. Also if I open it and refresh, all data in my application are gone.

Is there any tutorial, or something about How to add Service-based database and connect to this file using entity framework, wihout coppying it to output directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone need a solution for this case, there is one:

1. Create database in any program (could be visual studio)
2. Copy it to /bin/debug/
3. Put bin folder to your solution in Visual Studio
4. Select database and make Copy to Output - Do not copy
5. Edit connection string in entity framework to

   ```
   attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\file.mdf;
   ```

Database should now appear in Server Explorer in VS. You can now remove all newly created databases (leave only this one you copy to bin/debug/)
Now you will see correct database in Data Connections, and your program will update this one. You can easily coppy your solution to any other location, and connections will not be messed up.

Btw, I think this is entity framework error or DataDirectory should point to Solution folder, not bin/debug. I know we can change DataDirectory pointing...